# Jquery.Live events for onadd to dom elements

Tags: jquery

What if I want not only to add events for all future added, but also want to put some data in them, execute it as an init event for them. Is there possible to use something from live tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No event exists in the dom for item creation. The only option you have is to use the [liveQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) plugin which scans the dom every x milliseconds looking for selector matches. When a new element is found it will run a function.

I do not really like the overhead of this however it may give you the desired functionality.